# Updating a list within a class

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-formwizard

Is it possible to update a list within a class based on instance details?

I would like to do something like this:

```
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView
class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
        form_list = [ # a list of forms used per step
            (S1, Q1),
            (S2, Q2),
            (S3, Q3),
        ]
        def form_updater(self):
            if self.get_cleaned_data_for_step("0") != None:
                form_list.append((S3, Q3),)
            return form_list

#However, I get thrown an error when I try to make the following call:
ContactWizard.form_updater(ContactWizard)
## error:
get_cleaned_data_for_step() missing 1 required positional argument: 'step'
```

Any help or guidance that you can provide would be VERY greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you calling `ContactWizard`?

Comment: Outside of the class. If I try calling it within the class, its name is not recognized.

Comment: Please show the code you are using to call it

Comment: @LordElrond I have updated my post to clarify the structure of my call. This should be replicable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a **`classmethod`**:

```
class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
        form_list = [ # a list of forms used per step
            (S1, Q1),
            (S2, Q2),
            (S3, Q3),
        ]
   
        @classmethod
        def form_updater(cls):
            if cls.get_cleaned_data_for_step("0") != None:
                cls.form_list.append((S3, Q3),)
            return form_list
```

Comment: Thanks @LordElrond. When I run your code, I get an alternative error: 
form_updater() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. Any idea why this is?

Comment: @unicoder are you still passing the class into it?  you should call it without any arguments, like this: `ContactWizard.form_updater()`

Comment: Thanks, @LordElrond. When I make the call without any arguments, I get the following error (the same one I started with): get_cleaned_data_for_step() missing 1 required positional argument: 'step'. Any ideas why this may be the case?

Comment: @unicoder `get_cleaned_data_for_step()` is not a classmethod, so the `cls` instance isn't being implicitly passed to it.  I'm not familiar with the package you are using, so I wouldn't be able to help you further.  Instead, I'd recommend reading this docs for `formtools` and doing what they suggest.